# Find Tension of rope of a box moving upwards

Tags: kinematics

An box of mass m = 250kg is lowered by a rope. As the box is lowered its velocity changes over the distance d = 2.00m from initial velocity -4.00m/s to final velocity -1.00m/s. What is the tension of the rope

What I did was: figure out acceleration from distance and initial and final velocities, which in my case was -3.75 using that with the mass find Ft then adding it to mg (force of gravity)Answer I got was 3390N

Comment: Well, what have you tried?

Comment: @Arthur I did a similar question in the same fashion and got the right answer, 
What I did was: figure out acceleration from distance and initial and final velocities, which in my case was -3.75 using that with the mass find Ft then adding it to mg (force of gravity)

Comment: You have to assume something about how the velocity changes.  Is it linear with time, so the acceleration is constant?  The problem does not say that, but without that you cannot answer.  If you assume the tension is constant you have that.